# How to extract required string in below text using regular expressions in java?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to extract string between first and last in the below text.

Scenario 1:

```
"Select statement"+"\n"+
"first"+"\n"+
"I want to extract this" +"\n"+
"I want to extract this one too"+"\n"+
"last"+"\n"+
"end of the statement"+"\n"+
"first"+"\n"+
"I want to extract this" +"\n"+
"I want to extract this one too"+"\n"+
"last"+"\n"+
"end of the statement"
```

Scenario 2:

```
"Select statement"+"\n"+
"first"+"\n"+
"I want to extract this" +"\n"+
"last"+"\n"+
"end of the statement";
```

What would be the regex pattern in java to do this job? Pattern should be one but it should work in both the scenarios. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific about what structure the input has and what parts of it you want to match.

Comment: Thanks @freesum. I want to capture the text between first and last in both the scenarios. I added content to the question. I hope it will explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use lookarounds.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?s)(?<=\\bfirst\\n).*?(?=\\n?\\blast\\b)").matcher(s);
if(m.find())
  {
      System.out.println(m.group());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Avinash. It worked fine.  Sometimes my text contains only one line between first and last. How can we leverage above code to capture in both the scenarios? Thanks for your help.  I edited the question. I hope it will help in better understanding.

Comment: My current regex will work in that case also. You may also try my update.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Avinash. Worked like a gem..!!